# How to see failed machine learning records

Tags: machine-learning, ml.net

I am using the following code to create my machine learning model. The accuracy of the model is 0.76. I am just curious to know which records from my test data failed? Is there a way I can see those data?

```
// 1. Load the dataset for training and testing
        var trainData = ctx.Data.LoadFromTextFile<SentimentData>(trainDataPath, hasHeader: true);
        var testData = ctx.Data.LoadFromTextFile<SentimentData>(testDataPath, hasHeader: true);

        // 2. Build a tranformer/estimator to transform input data so that Machine Learning algorithm can understand
        IEstimator<ITransformer> estimator = ctx.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("Features", nameof(SentimentData.Text));

        // 3. - set the training algorithm and create the pipeline for model builder
        var trainer = ctx.BinaryClassification.Trainers.SdcaLogisticRegression();
        var trainingPipeline = estimator.Append(trainer);

        // 4. - Train the model
        var trainedModel = trainingPipeline.Fit(trainData);

        // 5. - Perform the preditions on the test data
        var predictions = trainedModel.Transform(testData);

        // 6. - Evalute the model
        var metrics = ctx.BinaryClassification.Evaluate(data: predictions);
```

Comment: Is it that you wish to see what your model predicted versus what it's actual ground truth is? I am familiar with a python solution to this if that will suffice.

Comment: yes exactly. Could you please give more details on the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `GetColumn` and `CreateEnumerable` methods, you can find the data that the model didn't predict correctly.

After you the metrics, use the `GetColumn` method on the predictions that were from the test data set to get the original label values. Then, use the `CreateEnuemrable` method to get the predictions that will hold the predicted values. Optionally, you can get the sentiment text as well.

```
var originalLabels = predictions.GetColumn<bool>("Label").ToArray();
var sentimentText = predictions.GetColumn<string>(nameof(SentimentData.SentimentText)).ToArray();
var predictedLabels = context.Data.CreateEnumerable<SentimentPrediction>(predictions, reuseRowObject: false).ToArray();
```

After getting the data, just loop through one of them (I did a count of the original labels) and you can access the data at each iteration. From there you can check if the actual label doesn't equal the predicted value to only print out the values that the model didn't get correctly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < originalLabels.Count(); i++)
{
    string outputText = String.Empty;

    if (originalLabels[i] != predictedLabels[i].Prediction)
    {
        outputText = $"Text - {sentimentText[i]} | ";
        outputText += $"Original - {originalLabels[i]} | ";
        outputText += $"Predicted - {predictedLabels[i].Prediction}";

        Console.WriteLine(outputText);
    }
}
```

With that you have the data that you need. :)

[image]

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I believe the method you are looking for can be found in the keras library.  The method should be `keras.models.predict_classes` as found on their [documentation page](http://faroit.com/keras-docs/1.0.0/models/sequential/).

This will provide you with an array of predicted outputs, which you can then compare to the ground truths. Visit the documentation to see the parameters.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is for Keras, though. He's wondering about how to do this in ML.NET.

Comment: Correct. I did not find any related library/method in ML.NET